# ¿Cómo Cargar Scripts JavaScript de Manera Asíncrona?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como se debe cargar de manera asíncrona con `js`.
Es decir tengo un formulario de **10 preguntas** , pero hay un `script` muy grande, pensemos que es un bucle de **15 segundos**.

Cuando cargo la pagina carga el formulario y comienza el bucle, pero se pasma **15 segundos** hasta que termina el bucle y durante ese tiempo no puedo realizar ninguna acción porque esta cargando parte del `script` que se usara después.

¿como cargo de manera asíncrona? ya que el atributo `async` no lo hace con solo ponerlo en `<script src"ejemplo.js" async/>`

Comment: Me parece que el problema real no es la carga del `archivo`, sino el `bucle` que demora `15s` y que "_pasma_"(?) el navegador.

Comment: Este post de mi buen amigo Jesús Angulo te será de utilidad: https://somostechies.com/async-vs-defer/#.WlUUEZdzK70

Comment: Ya probaste `<script type="text/javascript" src"ejemplo.js" async="async" />` deberia funcionar, si es así, me dices.

Comment: Me parece que el problema no está en la carga del script, está en la ejecución del mismo. Por lo tanto async o defer no ayudarían en este caso, puedes usar una [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), aunque debes revisar la [tabla de soporte en caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=promise) para ver si te puede ser de utilidad

Comment: Es correcto, el problema esta en el bucle, prueba comentar el bucle y veras que la pagina ya no se congela.